# problems facing start-ups and small firms in rural areas

Tags: grammar

This is a definition and an example phrase from a dictionary for the word "start-up":

a newly established business

Example: *problems facing start-ups and small firms in rural areas*

The grammar of the example phrase seems incorrect - do problems face start-ups and firms or start-ups and firms face problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facing is symmetric; if I am face-to-face with you, you are face-to-face with me, we are facing each other.

I do not see a problem here

> problems facing start-ups and small firms in rural areas

I might also say

> start-ups and small firms in rural areas face the following problems ...